# Authorization in SQL

Tags: sql

What does the following line do

```
CREATE SCHEMA Company AUTHORIZATION JSmith;
```

I know that it created a new schema or database but what does AUTHORIZATION do here ?
Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An SQL schema is identified by a schema name, and includes an authorization identifier to indicate the user or account who owns the schema, as well as descriptors for each element in the schema. Schema elements include tables, constraints, views, domains, and other constructs (such as authorization grants) that describe the schema. A schema is created via the CREATE SCHEMA statement, which can include all the schema elements' definitions. Alternatively, the schema can be assigned a name and authorization identifier, and the elements can be defined later. Forexample, the following statement creates a schema called COMPANY, owned by the user with authorization identifier JSMITH:

```
CREATE SCHEMA COMPANY AUTHORIZATION JSMITH;
```

From: https://github.com/mehikmat/One-Page-Hacks/wiki/One-Page-SQL-Fundamentals

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided creates a schema named 'Company' and sets 'JSmith' as its owner, who is a database-level principal that will own the schema.